# Javascript - how to access the fields of an exported object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, module

I have the following code, inside a constants.js file:

```
var constants = (
    conversationUsername: "user1", 
    conversationPassword: "pass1",
    conversationVersionDate: "date1", 
    conversationWorkspaceId: "work1"
};

module.exports.constants = constants;
```

Now, inside another file, I have the following:

```
var constants = require('./../constants');

console.log(constants);
```

Which outputs me:

```
{ constants:
   { conversationUsername: 'user1',
     conversationPassword: 'pass1',
     conversationVersionDate: 'date1',
     conversationWorkspaceId: 'work1' } }
```

Which I alright, I guess.

My question is, how can I now access these fields? If i try:

```
console.log(constants.conversationUsername);
```

I get:

> undefined

Comment: You export an object which has a *property* named constants, as shown in the output. Try ```constants.constants.conversationUsernane``` and it should work

Comment: You have a typo in your first code block: `(` should be `{`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access its `constants` field first

```
console.log(constants.constants.conversationUsername);
```

or `export` that object directly

```
module.exports = constants;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another fast forward solution is to extract the property from import:

```
var constants = require('./../constants').constants
```

or short

```
var {constants} = require('./../constants')
```

Then access the properties as expected:

```
constants.conversationUsername
```